# The optimal way to find leaves in a weighted full binary tree

Tags: algorithms, optimization, trees, search-algorithms, binary-trees

Let T be a full binary weighted tree. For a node v in T, the cost of going right is a i.e *w*(v, v.right) = *a* while *w*(v, v.left) = *b*

How do I find optimal paths to all leaves from the root. I don't think classical graph traversals are helpful in this context as I don't need to visit all nodes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In a tree, there's only one way to get from $A$ to $B$ so all routes that visit all leaves have the same cost.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: How many paths are there from a given leaf to the root?